# react-bootstrap-table, checkbox and textfield

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

couldn't find anything what relates to my problem hopefully someone has a link or the right answer.

Currently learning reactjs and trying to create a react-bootstrap-table to display some data. So the problem I have is with the checkBox.

The first problem I encounter is that I need to click the cell of the checkbox before I can change the state of the checkbox what is really anoying. I want to be able to just click it to check or uncheck it.
The Second is if you have some nice link how I can make it so that the column `refrences` is only editable if the checkbox is checked. I saw an example which seemed to do that but I didn't manage to get it to work.

```
const criteriaCovered = [
    'Automated acceptance test',
    'Developer test',
    'Manual acceptance test',
    'Unit test'
]
const cellEditProp = {
    mode: 'click',
    blurToSave: true
};

function checkBoxFormat (cell,row)
{
   return (
       <div>
           <input type="checkbox" ref="criticalData" checked={cell} />
       </div>
   );
}

const element = (
    <div>
        <BootstrapTable data={ac} cellEdit={cellEditProp}>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' isKey={true}             
                width="25%">Name</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='changeType' editable={{type: 
                'select', options: {values: ['Functionality','Layout']}}} 
                width="15%">Change Type</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='criticalData' className="checkbox-
                cell" dataFormat={checkBoxFormat} editable={{type: 
                'checkbox', options: {values: 'true:false'}}} 
                dataAlign="right" width="15%">Critical 
                data</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='criteriaCoveredBy' editable=
                {{type: 'select', options: {values: criteriaCovered}}} 
                width="25%">Criteria covered by</TableHeaderColumn>
            <TableHeaderColumn dataField='refrences' 
                width="20%">Refrences</TableHeaderColumn>
        </BootstrapTable>
    </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
    element,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Excuse me for my english writing, please.
It's my second language and I still need to improve on it a lot.

Comment: I had a similar problem as for your first one. However, I wasn't using the same library, instead I was generating my bootstrap table by hand. What I did was turning my rows into custom components, let's say <SelectRow/>, then I would append a onClick event to the whole row and change the checked value of the checkbox whenever the click event is fired. Do you think you can try to implement something like that?

Comment: So you were only using react and build you own grid with it by defining each row?

Comment: Yes, I was using only bootstrap classes and generating the table by myself. And my rows were custom components made to be clickable.

Comment: The Thread can be closed. As suggested by tibuurcio I am using now components in combination with a bootstrap-table, what seems to be working fine. However couldn't figure out how to fix the checkboxes to only display a checkbox instead of the value. I found a nice example code for the usage of bootstrap-table with component. If I find the link I will link it here.